# MySQL Prepared Statements for NodeJS Async Queries?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await, node-mysql

I've got an await query for which I need to use a MySQL statement;

```
 row_a = await mydb.query( str_sql_1 );
```

Here's the variable;

```
var str_sql_1  = 'INSERT INTO audioposts (title,userid,opid) VALUES (?,?,? )', [title, userid, opid];
```

But the error I'm getting is;

```
SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration
```

I also tried this;

```
 row_a = await mydb.query( str_sql_1 , [title, userid, opid]);
```

But got this error;

```
  Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

SoI do I get my `[title, userid, opid]` to replace  `?,?,?` in the code?

Comment: you need to do `mydb.query('string', [title, userid, opid])`, not `var a = 'string', [title, userid, opid]`, edit: second example is correct you just need to define `mydb`

Comment: That worked! If you put it as answer I'll select it.